# SQL Server : coalesce, the part of string is missing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coalesce

I have this code:

```
declare @results varchar(500)

select 
    @results = coalesce(@results+', ', '') + convert(varchar(12),k.t1)
from
(
    select 
        '('+cast(count(distinct(g.RoomID)) as varchar) + ') '+ rt.ClassName as t1
    from 
        db_pms.Guests g
        left join db_pms.RoomTypes rt 
            on rt.RoomTypeID=g.RoomTypeID
    where 
        g.GroupID = 47 and 
        g.Status >= 0
    group by 
        g.RoomTypeID,
        rt.ClassName
) k

select @results as results
```

The part

```
select 
    '('+ cast(count(distinct(g.RoomID))as varchar) + ') '+ rt.ClassName as t1
from 
    db_pms.Guests g
    left join db_pms.RoomTypes rt 
        on rt.RoomTypeID=g.RoomTypeID
where
    g.GroupID = 47 and 
    g.Status >= 0
group by 
    g.RoomTypeID,
    rt.ClassName
```

returns

```
(1) Люкс
(4) Полулюкс
(2) Стандарт DBL
(6) Стандарт TWN
(1) Стандарт+ TWN
```

and after using

```
select @results = coalesce(@results + ', ', '') +  convert(varchar(12),k.t1)
```

I get

```
(1) Люкс
(4) Полулюкс
(2) Стандарт
(6) Стандарт
(1) Стандарт
```

As you can see a part of string column is missing. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You should **definitely** use `nvarchar` for Cyrillic characters!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `varchar(12)` is too small to hold your results, due to the way MySQL (and SQL Server) counts length for varchar.  For example, running this query:

```
SELECT LENGTH( 'Стандарт TWN' )
```

Will give you a length of 20!  You need to increase the length, and you will be fine.

SQL Fiddle showing results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/5661/0

In SQL server you may wish to consider the use of nvarchar as well.

Comment: It's actually Microsoft **SQL Server** (not MySQL)

Comment: Whoops. :). Since SQL server lacks UTF8 support, you may see the same behavior based on the default encoding in the db.  Since you are not using nvarchar, I expect this is still the same issue.  Make sure you use UTF16.